# How can I speed up the redraw rate for the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, taskbar, scrolling, foobar2000

In foobar2000, I have a script for Columns UI that scrolls the song title across the taskbar button. I like it, but I wish it scrolled faster and more smoothly. I've read that the taskbar redraw rate for Windows 7 is set to one redraw per second, which is what causes it to be rather slow and choppy. I'd like to speed this up to about twice a second to give me a faster scroll. Is there a way to do this, perhaps in the registry editor? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Isn't it just scrolling by one character? If yes, then it has nothing to do with refresh rate (which I doubt is even used, refreshing is probably event-driven) and is controlled completely by Foobar.

Comment: Could you please post your script and show us your source? I think @gronostaj is right and foobar is just scrolling single characters